# Send request via proxy with Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, http-proxy, angular-httpclient

I am trying to send a request to an external API with a proxy with Angular 7 HttpClient and I can't seem to find a proxy option. What I am looking for is something like Node.js's request-promise HTTP client that supports proxies.

```
var request = require('request-promise').defaults({
    proxy:'http://username:password@host:port',
    strictSSL :false
});
```

Is something like this possible with Angular's HttpClient?

Answer (score 0):

This is good document refer [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1896)

check this also [Proxy To Backend](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

> sample https proxy configuration

```
{
  "/angular": {
     "target":  {
       "host": "github.com",
       "protocol": "https:",
       "port": 443
     },
     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

official way is like below

edit "start" of your `package.json` to look below

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

create a new file called proxy.conf.json in the root of the project and inside of that define your proxies like below

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://api.yourdomai.com",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Important thing is that you use `npm start` instead of `ng serve`